Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Diplom\PycharmProjects\Yolo01\Roboflow-4.py", line 4, in <module> import roboflow
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Diplom\PycharmProjects\Yolo01\Roboflow-4.py", line 4, in 
import roboflow
File "C:\Users\Diplom\PycharmProjects\Yolo01.venv\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver_init_.py", line 8, in 
from ._cext import (
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: The specified module was not found.
Python 3.11 , PyCharm Community Edition 2023.3.5 , windows 10.
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import roboflow
import numpy as np

class VideoPlayer:
    def __init__(self, video_file, master=None, width=480, height=270):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master, height=height, width=width)
        self.delay = int(1000 / self.cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
        self.photo = None

pip list
Package                Version

certifi                2023.7.22
chardet                4.0.0
charset-normalizer     3.3.2
colorama               0.4.6
contourpy              1.2.1
cycler                 0.10.0
fonttools              4.51.0
idna                   2.10
kiwisolver             1.4.5
matplotlib             3.8.4
msvc-runtime           14.34.31931
numpy                  1.26.4
opencv-python          4.8.1.78
opencv-python-headless 4.8.0.74
packaging              24.0
pillow                 10.3.0
pip                    24.0
pyparsing              2.4.7
python-dateutil        2.9.0.post0
python-dotenv          1.0.1
python-magic           0.4.27
PyYAML                 6.0.1
requests               2.31.0
requests-toolbelt      1.0.0
roboflow               1.1.27
setuptools             68.2.0
six                    1.16.0
tk                     0.1.0
tqdm                   4.66.2
urllib3                2.2.1
wget                   3.2
wheel                  0.41.2
The following steps did not help:
pip install msvc-runtime
pip uninstall roboflow
pip installs roboflow
pip uninstall kiwisolver
pip install kiwisolver
python -m pip install roboflow

Seems like importing _cext: comes from the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable, try downloading your verison from the link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

installed it. a new error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Diplom\PycharmProjects\Yolo01\Roboflow-4.py", line 7, in 
class VideoPlayer:
File "C:\Users\Diplom\PycharmProjects\Yolo01\Roboflow-4.py", line 17, in VideoPlayer
rf = roboflow(api_key="ххх")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

It's working. wrote: from roboflow import Roboflow
